# How should I design makefile hierarchy?

Tags: makefile, hierarchy, gnu-make

I'm learning to write make file but I don't really have a clear mind how should I design my makefile hierarchy. It is not easy to describe so I'll post exactly what I have right now and any suggestions are appreciated.

So what I want to ask is

```
1. Does my common.mk a general practice to contain TOP_DIR variable?
2. How can I make makefile(1) call makefile(2) if l_util objects are missing.
```

I have such folder hierarchy which I used to learn c++ algorithms:

```
-learning
    - introduction_to_algorithms
        - insertion_sort
            - insertion_sort.cpp
            - makefile(1)
    - l_util
        - include
            - l_util_stlutil.h
            - l_util_numberutil.h
        - l_util_stlutil.cpp
        - l_util_numberutil.cpp
        - makefile(2)
    - common.mk
```

where insertion_sort.cpp includes l_util files. Here are my make files:

common.mk:

```
1 # This must be the first this in Makefile.common
2 TOP_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
3
4 CC := g++
```

makefile(1):

```
1 include ../../common.mk
2
3 CPP_SRCS := \
4 insertion_sort.cpp \
5
6 LIBS := \
7
8 OBJS := \
9 insertion_sort.o \
10
11 OTHER_OBJS := \
12 $(TOP_DIR)l_util/l_util_stlutil.o \
13 $(TOP_DIR)l_util/l_util_numberutil.o \
14
15 INCLUDE_PATH := \
16 $(TOP_DIR)l_util/include
17
18 TASK := insertion_sort.tsk
19
20 # Tool invocations
21 $(TASK): $(OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS)
22     $(CC) -o $(TASK) $(OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
23     @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
24
25 $(OBJS): $(CPP_SRCS)
26     $(CC) -c -Wall -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CPP_SRCS)
27     @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
28
29 # Other Targets
30 .PHONY: clean
31 clean:
32     -$(RM) $(OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS) $(TASK)
```

makefile(2):

```
1 include ../common.mk
2
3 CPP_SRCS := \
4 l_util_stlutil.cpp \
5 l_util_numberutil.cpp \
6
7 LIBS := \
8
9 OBJS := \
10 l_util_numberutil.o \
11 l_util_stlutil.o \
12
13 $(OBJS): $(CPP_SRCS)
14     $(CC) -c -Wall $(CPP_SRCS)
15     @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
16
17 # Other Targets
18 .PHONY: clean
19 clean:
20     -$(RM) $(OBJS)
```

When I run make in insertion_sort folder I get:

```
1 g++ -c -Wall -I../../l_util/include insertion_sort.cpp
2 Finished building target: insertion_sort.o
3 c++    -c -o ../../l_util/l_util_stlutil.o ../../l_util/l_util_stlutil.cpp
4 c++    -c -o ../../l_util/l_util_numberutil.o ../../l_util/l_util_numberutil.cpp
5 g++ -o insertion_sort.tsk insertion_sort.o  ../../l_util/l_util_stlutil.o   
  ../../l_util/l_util_numberutil.o
6 Finished building target: insertion_sort.tsk
```

I don't think line 3 and 4 are generated by makefile(2), it seems like it's been called automatically without calling makefile(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some code in makefile1:
$(OTHER_OBJS):
    make -C “The absolute dir of your makefile2"

your should tell makefile1, where is your makefile2, "make -C" will do that, and make makefile1 call makefile2.

Answer (score 1):

You should use GNUmake and take advantage of its `include` functionality to build a single hierarchy of dependencies across the entire project.

This is, in practice, the *only* realistic way of creating a make-based build system that does incremental build correctly. This is they way `kbuild`, the Linux kernel build system works.

See [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf).